# How to generate an excel file and send it in the response using spring boot

Tags: excel, spring-boot

I have a list of employee records in a table, i want to **generate report** out of it. Is there a way to generate and send the generated report in **excel format** to the **browser** in response.FYI I'm using **Spring boot** and **reactjs**.

Comment: Did you try anything? Show us your work so we might help you?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)

There are some examples of creating XLS[X] files in their [developers guide](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook)

A quick example from there

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
//Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

// Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
// Create a cell and put a value in it.
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(1);

// Or do it on one line.
row.createCell(1).setCellValue(1.2);
row.createCell(2).setCellValue(
     createHelper.createRichTextString("This is a string"));
row.createCell(3).setCellValue(true);

// Write the output to a file
try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls")) {
    wb.write(fileOut);
}
```